# Weirdest bug I have ever encountered. Possible V8 optimization issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, v8

It's going to be difficult to explain this one. It took me three days to figure out.

I'm making a serialization library and I'm trying to make it fast. All it does is serialize objects to and from a buffer.

I noticed that if I ran my benchmark first, it would take around 500 milliseconds to encode. However, if I ran my test suite first, my benchmark afterwards would take around 1300 milliseconds to encode.

This was extremely weird because they were operating with two completely different objects with nothing shared at all.

I went through my program and started benchmarking every single line until I finally found the line accounting for the 800 ms difference.

It was this line in a function: `for (var j = arrLen; j < refLen; j++) {`

Not the body of the loop either. Just the header of the for loop.

I had no idea how to fix it. Except recently just on a whim I tried duplicating the function (just copy and paste) and renaming it to include a 0 at the end of the name.

I then had my test suite call the first function and my benchmark call the second function. The time difference disappeared. The function contents and parameter list are exactly the same.

**My leading theory is:** The first time this function is called, the function is optimized and I guess the loop is unrolled. This is why calling the benchmark first doesn't have the problem: because the first time this is called it is optimized. However, if you call it later, it is not optimized for the inputs given, and thus runs really slow.

**My question is:** short of just copying and pasting this function thousands of times and having each encode use a different version of this function, is there any way to fix this issue as to remove the time difference? A difference between 500 milliseconds and 1300 milliseconds is huge.

I've been trying to make a test case of this but it is extremely difficult because this bug is so obscure. Hopefully my text description was enough.

**Edit:** Here's the function being called.

```
function endEncodeArray(ref, arrLen, writeRepeatFunction, wBuffer) {
  var refLen = ref.length;
  if (refLen - arrLen > 0) {
    for (var j = arrLen; j < refLen; j++) { // <-- this line slow
      writeRepeatFunction(ref[j], wBuffer);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:** The approach of manually writing out the function as a string, evaling it, and then calling that seems to fix the performance problem. Since I can't figure out how to isolate the test case, I suppose I'll just use this as a bandage fix.

Comment: Don't listen to benchmarks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU They're a mystery on their own.

Comment: @Rudie: I also forgot to mention: I benchmarked this with `console.time`, `benchmark.js`, and with my own `process.hrtime` solution. This issue is shown to be happening with all three. It is a very real problem that is causing very real performance losses.

Comment: @ChronBag, a function is marked after about 100-150 calls with consistent input for optimization. The engine doesn't attempt to optimize everything that get's within range of sight. I've never heard, that loops are unrolled in JS, but I may be wrong. I'd rather think, that maybe the types of `start` or `len` have changed. maybe from (signed!!) `int32` to `float`? or maybe you're wrong with the bottlenect and one of the types in the loop-body has changed in your benchmark, wich may have caused v8 to deopt the function? could you post/link some code?

Comment: @Thomas: `arrLen` and `refLen` are always the same data-type (small uints). I updated my post to include the function. I also forgot to mention: I went through [this list](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) and [this list](https://github.com/vhf/v8-bailout-reasons) and didn't find anything that would be causing a de-opt.

Comment: Sure seems like you should be filing a bug report.

Comment: @squint: I'd have to nail the test case first for that. I'll spend a couple hours trying to reproduce it with a smaller program. Also, even if it is a bug with v8, I'd rather just find a workaround that avoids the de-opt because I want my program to be efficient on older versions of node as well.

Comment: @ChronBag If your code is open-source and you can't reduce it to a simple reproduction then you can just post the whole code that reproduces it. People with V8 experience will be able to reduce it much faster themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You may face deopt exactly because your benchmark and test, as you mentioned, work with two completely different objects. See http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html for details, hope it helps.

Comment: I just checked, and even if I use the same object, the problem still occurs. I'll still read the article though. Might provide some other insight.